# Material for web components Integration with Angular 4

Tags: angular, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm trying to integrate [material components for web](https://material.io/components/web/) which is the latest release from Google as the successor of material design Lite. I tried all possible ways but, Couldn't integrate it with angular 4. The example link from Google is also broken. Could anyone please guide me in the integration of the same? A sample project on github or steps to integrate and use the components will be very much helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have their docs [here](https://material.io/components/web/docs/framework-integration/) and examples [here](https://material.io/components/web/docs/framework-integration/) and [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/packages/mdc-menu/simple/index.js). On the first link you have a step-by-step implementation on Angular 2.

Comment: @BogdanC, Ì followed them, I tried to include the css and js files via, components, angular-cli, index.html and style.scss. but it throws be ERR:ABORTED. I dono where I'm making the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Material Components for the Web has pretty good documentation for how to integrate with other frameworks, see https://material.io/components/web/docs/framework-integration/.

There are also third party efforts that already provide the integration. You could look at those for inspiration. Or you could actually use them instead of trying to reinvent that wheel again. The main README links to the Blox Material library for Angular integration, see https://blox.src.zone/material#/guides and https://github.com/src-zone/material. (Disclaimer: I am a developer for Blox Material).